# How to declare an explicit receiver on Android 9

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I'm having a little trouble with declaring a receiver in manifest and getting it to work.

I know since android 8.0 there can't be any implicit broadcast receivers declared in manifest, but it can be explicit receivers declared.

So I declared mine like this in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".util.AppReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.ibermatica.mime.starttracking" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

After that, I install the app in the phone in debug mode and place a breakpoint in the onReceive method, which has this code:

```
if(intent.getAction() != null){
    switch (intent.getAction()){
        case Util.START_TRACKING:
            Intent i;
            i = new Intent(context, LocationUpdatesService.class);
            context.startService(i);
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

So I send the broadcast message from command line having the app in background with this command:

*adb shell am broadcast -a com.ibermatica.mime.starttracking*

But nothing happens, nor the receiver gets called. What is wrong or what do I have to do to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is not possible to declare an explicit receiver just for my app? Making a foreground service just to listen for broadcast messages with a notification message would be really annoying to have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know since android 8.0 there can't be any implicit broadcast receivers declared in manifest, but it can be explicit receivers declared.

"Explicit" and "implicit" are terms used to refer to types of `Intent` objects, not manifest entries.

> But nothing happens, nor the receiver gets called.

Correct. You are creating an implicit `Intent` on the command line, and implicit `Intent` broadcasts generally do not work on Android 8.0+.

Try:

```
adb shell am broadcast -n com.whatever/.util.AppReceiver -a com.ibermatica.mime.starttracking
```

where you replace `com.whatever` with your application ID.

Comment: Okay, understood the part of explicit and implicit terms, thank you!
But I must be doing something wrong, because the command is not working, I type:
adb shell am broadcast -n com.ibermatica.mime/.util.AppReceiver
being com.ibermatica.mime my application Id, but nothing happens. I also tried:
adb shell am broadcast -n com.ibermatica.mime.starttracking/.util.AppReceiver
being .starttracking in the intent-filter, but it isn't working either... Any clue on what might be happening?
Thank you very much, your help is really appreciated!

Comment: @misterpresid: Your code depends on an action string (`switch (intent.getAction())`), and I don't know how your real code sends this broadcast. I updated my answer to add back in the `-a com.ibermatica.mime.starttracking` to add the action string to the command line.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but it's not working either. I have a method breakpoint in onReceive(...) and is not reaching it. 
I don't have to do anything else than declare it in the manifest and have the code in onReceive, right?
Again, thank you very much for you help!

Comment: @misterpresid: Another problem is `android:exported="false"`. This blocks your ability to send broadcasts to this receiver from outside the app, which includes `adb shell am broadcast`. Either temporarily export this receiver, or switch to doing your testing in the project itself (e.g., instrumentation tests).

Comment: Okay, I just tried that and I'm really dumb. I copied your code and pasted it without changing com.whatever. Having changed that along with the export works like a charm. Thank you very very much!!